# How to properly substitute a string containing spaces in my script

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync

In my script I've got:

```
sshkey="/Users/me/some path/with spaces/id_rsa"
dstport=...
dstparent=...
dstuserhost=...

rsync -az --delete -e "ssh -i $sshkey -p $dstport" $src $dstuserhost:$dstparent
```

And when I run it, I get:

> rsync: link_stat "/Users/me/some" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding single quotes around `$sshkey` would solve it:

```
rsync -az --delete -e "ssh -i '$sshkey' -p '$dstport'" "$src" "$dstuserhost:$dstparent"
```

The `$sshkey` value would be expanded by your interactive shell before calling `rsync` because it's within a double quoted string, but the single quotes would stop the string from being further split when `rsync` calls `ssh` to set up the connection.

That assumes `$sshkey` doesn't contain single quote characters itself.

Comment: Doesn't work: rsync: `link_stat "/Users/me/some" failed: No such file or directory (2)` The single quotes are getting lost somehow. However, if I add spaces like this `' $sshkey '` the quotes are not lost and rsync sees the full path padded with spaces, which makes it an invalid path.

Comment: @DesmondHume Are you running `bash`? I can use the code in my answer in the default `bash` 3.2.57 on macOS (with the default `rsync`) as well as in later releases of the shell on other operating systems (OpenBSD and Linux).

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)`

Comment: @DesmondHume When I'm testing on macOS, the message I get is a warning that I don't have the file (since I don't): `Warning: Identity file /Users/me/some path/with spaces/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.`

Comment: This is weird. I added single quotes but kept the unrelated `$src $dstuserhost:$dstparent` the same. But when I used `"$src" "$dstuserhost:$dstparent"` instead it suddenly worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject some "inner" quotes. I would say

```
printf -v rsh_cmd 'ssh -i "%s" -d "%s"' "$sshkey" "$dstport"
...
rsync ... -e "$rsh_cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to that `-e` option of `rsync` is not a shell command line, it's an `rsync` command line. `rsync` parses it with its own rules which differ from that of Bourne shells.

Like all shells, it treats space characters as argument separators and like Bourne shells it treats single quotes and double quotes (but not backslash) as quoting operators. It doesn't do any of the shell expansions (like `$var`, `$(cmd)`, `*.txt`, `~user`...).

So to embed an arbitrary argument in that pseudo command line, you could either enclose it double quotes except for the double quote character themselves (which you'd then enclose in single quotes) or enclose them in single quotes except for the single quote character themselves (which you'd then enclose in double quotes).

For example if your ssh key file was `/cygdrive/c/John Doe/.ssh/John "Dude" Doe's.rsa`, the argument to `-e` should be something like `'/cygdrive/c/John Doe/.ssh/John "Dude" Doe'"'"'s.rsa'` or `"/cygdrive/c/John Doe/.ssh/John "'"'"Dude"'"'" Doe's.rsa"`.

You could define a dedicated function to do that *rsync-quoting* like:

```
# ksh93/bash/zsh syntax:
rsync_quote() {
  local arg="$1"
  arg=${arg//\'/\'\"\'\"\'}
  printf "'%s'\n" "$var"
}

rsync -e "ssh -i $(rsync_quote "$sshkey") -p $dstport" ...
```

Another option would be to pass a shell as argument to `-e` which would then be the one interpreting the `ssh` command line. An advantage to that is that that shell could then do the variable expansions.

```
KEY=$sshkey PORT=$dstport SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i "$KEY" -p "$PORT" "$@"' \
  rsync -e "sh -c 'eval \"\$SSH_COMMAND\"' sh" ...
```

If you run it with `strace -fe execve -s 999`, you see it unroll:

```
execve("/usr/bin/rsync", ["rsync", "-e", "sh -c 'eval \"$SSH_COMMAND\"' sh", "1/", "localhost:2/"], 0x7ffc03b83678 /* 74 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 7208 attached
[pid  7208] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "eval \"$SSH_COMMAND\"", "sh", "localhost", "rsync", "--server", "-e.LsfxC", ".", "2/"], 0x7ffcc6ad0f28 /* 74 vars */) = 0
[pid  7209] execve("/usr/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "-i", "/cygdrive/c/John Doe/.ssh/John \"Dude\" Doe's.rsa", "-p", "2222", "localhost", "rsync", "--server", "-e.LsfxC", ".", "2/"], 0x5651a0c144a8 /* 74 vars */) = 0
```